# Trying to get dropdown menu with values from database but getting array to string conversion error (YII2)

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

This is my code:

```
<?= 
    $rates= ApplicantRating::find()->all();     
    $listData= \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($rates,'id','name'); 
    
    echo $form->field($model,'name')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'Select...']);
?>
```

I have a:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Array to string conversion error

and I cannot understand why. It is highlighting the line `$rates= ApplicantRating::find()->all();` as the problem. Any suggestions pls?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `<?php` tag instead of echo shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

`<?= [sentence here]` is the same as `<?php echo [sentence here]`
So, what happens is php tries to `echo $rates`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `<?=` to `<?php` like follows:

```
<?php 
    $rates= ApplicantRating::find()->all();     
    $listData= \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($rates,'id','name'); 
    
    echo $form->field($model,'name')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'Select...']);
?>
```